# What regular expression will match a domain name without a 3rd level?

Tags: regex

What is the most efficient regex that will match these domains, without having to specify any rules to ignore?

Example matches:

```
domain.com
test.com
example.net
company.org
```

Example Ignore:

```
dev.domain.com
m.domain.com
www.domain.com
```

Any top level domain is possible. Essentially I am trying to make sure the domain doesnt already have a 3rd level.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: What about domain.co.uk (for example)?

Comment: Are domains like 'domain.com.au' or 'domain.co.nz' acceptable? If so, you'll need to use a list like the Mozilla Public Suffix List: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/dns/effective_tld_names.dat?raw=1 (So your regex will be *very* long.)

Comment: Probably you can grab the file, understand what it means, and construct a regex programatically from the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match a domain with any TLD use this:

`^[^.\s]+\.[^.\s]+$`

Comment: Will this match domains like .co.uk ?

Comment: No. It would be impossible to differentiate between `dev.domain.com` and `apple.co.uk` without either a list of two part extensions or a character limit, like 2 characters to the 2nd of three parts.